# Measure or profile use of AVX2 (and other advanced instruction sets) instructions used by programm

Tags: profiling, cpu-usage, instructions, avx2, amd-processor

We are chasing some weird hardware failures on AMD Threadrippers. I came across some evidence that AVX2/AVX-512 instructions can lead to weird behaviour (https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=22382946).

Is there a generic way of measuring or profiling the use of AVX2/AVX-512 instructions of a running program or machine? For now it would be enough for me to get a ball-park of how many of these instructions are being used in a given time frame. I do not necessarily need to pin it down to the actual program using them. The more detailed the profiling / attribution of AVX2/AVX-512 instruction use by program or time is the better.

I would prefer tools that run in Linux.

Comment: Zen 1 / Zen 2 don't decode AVX512 instructions at all.  Any EVEX prefix should raise a #UD illegal instruction exception.

Comment: Your best bet is probably Intel's SDE which can give you an instruction-mix breakdown.  At least on Intel CPUs, there's no HW perf counter support for counting AVX vs. SSE instructions (including integer), only FP math instructions.  [Ubuntu - how to tell if AVX or SSE, is current being used by CPU app?](//stackoverflow.com/q/60329437) and [How do I monitor the amount of SIMD instruction usage](//stackoverflow.com/q/60104698)